Open Weather App Script authorisation blocked by Google
We have a script from weather API for google sheets that when we run, Google does not allow authorisation. The script calls to open weather api to get city weather data, to get city level data back on temperature, conditions etc.
I have seen that there are some issues where app scripts are blocked for security reasons, but do not find any resolution on what steps to take to fix the issue. Message:

This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

Anyone had a similar issue, and have been able to resolve it? (small sample below)
var WEATHER_SHEET = 'weather_feed'
var API_KEY_SHEET = 'API_key'
var BASE_API = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group'
var HOW_MANY_CITIES_FETCHED_IN_ONE_CALL = 20
var CITY_ID_COLUMN = 'openweather_city_id'

We expect on run that authorisation is successful
var WEATHER_SHEET = 'weather_feed'
var API_KEY_SHEET = 'API_key'
var BASE_API = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group'
var HOW_MANY_CITIES_FETCHED_IN_ONE_CALL = 20
var CITY_ID_COLUMN = 'openweather_city_id'

function updateContent() {
  var apiSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(API_KEY_SHEET)
  API_KEY =    apiSheet.getRange("A2").getValue()
  
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(WEATHER_SHEET)
  var cityIds = getColumnFromSheetAsArray(mainSheet, CITY_ID_COLUMN)
  var weatherData = chunkArray(cityIds, HOW_MANY_CITIES_FETCHED_IN_ONE_CALL).reduce(function(acc, ids) {
    return acc.concat(getCurrentWeatherForCities(ids))
  }, []).map(flattenOpenWeatherObject)
  
  writeData(mainSheet, weatherData)
}

function chunkArray(arr, len) {
  var chunks = []
  var i = 0
  var n = arr.length
  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len))
  } return chunks
}

function getJSON(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  return JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
} 

function getIndexForColumn(sheet, columnHeader) {
  var headerData = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())[0]
  return headerData.indexOf(columnHeader)
}

function getColumnFromSheetAsArray(sheet, columnHeader) {
  var index = getIndexForColumn(sheet, columnHeader)
  var rows = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn())
  return rows.map(function(row) {
    return row[index]
  }) 
}

function writeData(sheet, data) {
  var headerData = Object.keys(data[0])
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(),headerData.length).clearContent()
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, headerData.length).setValues([headerData])
  var matrixData = data.map(function(el) {
    return headerData.map(function(key) {
      return el[key]
    })
  })
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, matrixData.length, headerData.length).setValues(matrixData)
}

function getOpenWeatherUrl(cityIds) {
  return BASE_API + '?units=metric&appid=' + API_KEY + '&id='+cityIds.join(',')
}

function getCurrentWeatherForCities(cityIds) {
  var weathers = getJSON(getOpenWeatherUrl(cityIds)).list || []
  return orderedWeathers(cityIds, weathers)
}
  
function orderedWeathers(cityIds, weathers) {
  var weathersByID = weathers.reduce(function(weathersByID, weather) {
    weathersByID[weather.id] = weather;
    return weathersByID;
  }, {})

  return cityIds.map(function(cityId) {
    return weathersByID[cityId]
  })
}

function flattenOpenWeatherObject(weather) {
  return {
    weather_main: (weather.weather || [{}])[0].main || '', 
    description: (weather.weather || [{}])[0].description || '',
    temperature: (weather.main || {}).temp || 0,
    rain: (weather.rain || {})['3h'] || 0,
    wind_speed: (weather.wind || {})['speed'] || 0,
    snow: (weather.snow || {})['3h'] || 0,
    clouds: (weather.clouds || {})['all'] || 0,
    _timestamp: new Date()
  }
}


issue resolved via authorising via another login, and clicking on advanced and continue to authorise. hope this helps other people that have seen the issue

issue resolved via...  I am pleased that you resolved the question. May I suggest that you post an answer to the question (as opposed to including your successful solution in comments) so that future users will know  that the issue was resolved and more easily find the solution.

As reported by The Master there are a couple of issues about this problem on the Google Apps Script issue tracker:


https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176138626

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181220763



Notes:

As of June 28, 2024, the first issue is marked as duplicating the second issue.
The second link has the status "Won't fix (Obsolete)".
Comment by a Googler:


jp...@google.comjp...@google.com #76 Dec 13, 2023 02:57PM
It's related to the security of the user and not a particular bug related to code. There is no further action to take here, beyond improving documentation.

See the above-linked The Master's answer for some workarounds.
Related

Unable to authorize ANY external Google Apps Script scope on any ANY file
Can not run trivial app script bound to new blank document - get "This app is blocked"


I voted early to close the question as it needs debugging details, so I can't vote to close it as duplicate.
